# qdockwidget not below qmenubar

Tags: go, qt5

I'm using this Qt binding for Go https://github.com/therecipe/qt, but have some issues combining `QDockWidget` with `QMenuWidget`.

I've created the main window with the QT creator that spits out a `mainwindow.ui` file (see below).

Now I'd like to dynamically add docking widgets to the window, however, when doing so the left docker is on the same level as the menu bar, meaning it moves the menu bar to the right. 
I would like to have the docker below the static bar.

[image]

In the image the "Left Dock Widget" should be below the menu bar

Below is the relevant code for setting everything up:

ui.go

```
func LoadFormToWidget(fileName string) *widgets.QWidget {
    file := utils.OpenQFile(fileName)
    widget := uitools.NewQUiLoader(nil).Load(file, nil)
    file.Close()

    return widget
}
```

base.go

```
func SetupUI() {
    mainWindowWidget := ui.LoadFormToWidget("src/ui/mainwindow.ui")

    mainWindow := widgets.NewQMainWindow(nil, 0)
    mainWindow.SetCentralWidget(mainWindowWidget)

    createDocker(mainWindow)
    setupDockingCorners(mainWindow)

    mainWindow.ShowMaximized()
}

func createDocker(mainWindow *widgets.QMainWindow) {
    leftDocker := createLeftDocker()
    mainWindow.AddDockWidget(core.Qt__LeftDockWidgetArea, leftDocker)
}

func createLeftDocker() *widgets.QDockWidget {
    leftDockWidget := widgets.NewQDockWidget("Left Dock Widget", nil, 0)
    leftDockWidget.SetAllowedAreas(core.Qt__LeftDockWidgetArea)
    leftDockWidget.SetFloating(true)
    leftDockWidget.SetWidget(widgets.NewQPushButton2("PushButton", nil))
    return leftDockWidget
}
```

mainwindow.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>1025</width>
    <height>596</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="sizePolicy">
   <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
    <horstretch>0</horstretch>
    <verstretch>0</verstretch>
   </sizepolicy>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <property name="autoFillBackground">
   <bool>false</bool>
  </property>
  <property name="documentMode">
   <bool>true</bool>
  </property>
  <property name="dockNestingEnabled">
   <bool>true</bool>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget"/>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>1025</width>
     <height>23</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="sizePolicy">
    <sizepolicy hsizetype="MinimumExpanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
     <horstretch>0</horstretch>
     <verstretch>0</verstretch>
    </sizepolicy>
   </property>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuFile">
    <property name="title">
     <string>File</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="actionSettings"/>
    <addaction name="separator"/>
    <addaction name="actionQuit"/>
   </widget>
   <addaction name="menuFile"/>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
  <action name="actionSettings">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Settings</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionQuit">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Quit</string>
   </property>
  </action>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: I see widgets only, but where your layouts?